# need help. instead of ascii value,4 million+

Tags: c, ascii

[image]

most of those chars appears like some random numbers instead of their ascii value, why is that? and why it still working?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h> 

#define SIZE 10

void arrayFiller(int v[]);
void charTimes(int v[]);
void arrayPrinter(int v[]);
void CharlessOn(int v[]);
void stringToDigit(char string_num[]);

int main() {
int vec[SIZE];
char string_num[50];
arrayFiller(vec);
arrayPrinter(vec);
charTimes(vec);
CharlessOn(vec);
gets(string_num);
stringToDigit(string_num);
}


void arrayFiller(int v[]) {
    printf("Please write down first a character and then number and repeat it 5 times, \nThe                         
    character represents the character you want to print,\nAnd the number is the number of times the 
    character will be printed.\n");
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    int checker = 0;
    if (i % 2 == 0 || i == 0) {
        scanf("%c", &v[i]);
    }
    else {
        do {
            if (checker>0)
                printf("The number must be between 1 and 10,Try again please.\n");
            scanf("%d", &v[i]);
            checker++;
        } while (v[i] < 1 || v[i]>10);
        getchar();
    }
   }
 }

void charTimes(int v[]) {
    int k = 1;
    printf("\nHere is the Char few times\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i += 2) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v[k]; j++) {
            printf("%c,", v[i]);
        }
        k += 2;
    }

}

void arrayPrinter(int v[]) {
    printf("\n here is your array:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d,", v[i]);
    }
}

void CharlessOn (int v[]) {
    int charless,k = 1;
    printf("\nPlease write down the character you want to get rid of:\n");
    scanf("%c", &charless);
    printf("%d", charless);
    printf("\nHere is the string without the char you chose:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i += 2) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v[k]&& v[i]!=charless; j++) { 
            printf("%c,", v[i]);
        }
        k += 2;
    }
}

void stringToDigit(char string_num[]){
    int holder=0,number=0;
   for(int i = 0; string_num[i] != NULL;i++){
      number*=10;
    holder=string_num[i];
    holder-=48;
   number+=holder;
}
    printf("the number is %d",number);
}
```

it was pretty finished for my homework lets say but i missed one question so i am redoing it, and i found out an problem, the first e that i wrote has strage value while the second e that has starge value aswell doesnt much the first e

Comment: Ok, I understand that English is not your first language, but....  what is this 'e' thing?

Comment: Reading the screenshot, it looks like the author enters an e which is stored, and then they enter an e again expecting it to be removed and it isn't removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `scanf("%c", &v[i])`, you are supposed to pass the address of a `char` for `%c`, but `&v[i]` is the address of an `int`. `scanf` has filled in one byte of `v[i]` and left the rest uninitialized.

Modify your code to pass the address of a `char` to `scanf` for `%c`.

Comment: yup i changed the array to char and it works great :D

Answer (score 0):

In addition to first answer.
Looking into function **arrayFiller**, `if (i % 2 == 0 || i == 0)`  is redundant. It is identically the same as `if (i % 2 == 0)`
When checking the value of a character it should be treated as a character, you must compare with chars, `'1'` is not the same as `1`, also the digits starts from **0 to 9** instead of **1 to 10**. So instead of instead of `while (v[i] < 1 || v[i]>10);` you should compare like `while (v[i] < '0' || v[i]>'9');`.
I don't understand the full meaning of all your functions. You have to provide some more details on what is the expected correct behavior of your code.

Comment: thank you, you are right i will fix it